# Escape line beginning and end in bracket expressions in sed

Tags: sed

How do you escape line beginning and line end in bracket expressions in sed?

For example, let's say I want to replace both comma, line beginning, and line end in each line with pipe:

```
echo "a,b,c" | sed 's/,/|/g'
# a|b|c
echo "a,b,c" | sed 's/^/|/g'
# |a,b,c
echo "a,b,c" | sed 's/$/|/g'
# a,b,c|
echo "a,b,c" | sed 's/[,^$]/|/g'
# a|b|c
```

I would expect the last command to produce `|a|b|c|`. I also tried escaping the line beginning and line end via backslash, with no change.

Comment: The answer to `How do you escape line beginning and line end in bracket expressions in sed` is **you cannot**. Bracket expressions represent lists of characters, they no not have any concept of "beginning of line" or "end of line" - there are other regexp components that you can use for that such as `^` (start of string) and `$` (end of string) when applied to a string that doesn't contain newline characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU `sed` with extended regular expressions, you can do:

```
$ echo "a,b,c" | /opt/gnu/bin/sed -E 's/^|,|$/|/g'
|a|b|c|
$
```

The `-E` option enables the extended regular expressions, as does `-r`, but `-E` is also used by other `sed` variants for the same purpose, unlike `-r`.

However, for reasons which elude me, the BSD (macOS) variant of `sed` produces:

```
$ echo "a,b,c" | sed -E 's/^|,|$/|/g'
|a|b|c
$
```

I can't think why.

If this variability is unacceptable, go with the three-substitution solution:

```
$ echo "a,b,c" | sed -e "s/^/|/" -e "s/$/|/" -e "s/,/|/g"
|a|b|c|
$
```

which should work with any variant of `sed`.  However, note that `echo "" | sed …3 subs…` produces `||` whereas the `-E` variant produces `|`.  I'm not sure if there's an easy fix for that.

---

You tried this, but it didn't do what you wanted:

```
$ echo "a,b,c" | sed 's/[,^$]/|/g'
a|b|c
$
```

This is what should be expected. Inside character classes, most special characters lose their special-ness. There is nothing special about `$` (or `,` but it isn't a metacharacter anyway) in a character class; `^` is only special at the start of the class and it negates the character class.  That means that what follows shows the correct, expected behaviour from this permutation of the contents of your character class:

```
$ echo "a,b\$\$b,c" | sed 's/[^,$]/|/g'
|,|$$|,|
$
```

It mapped all the non-comma, non-dollar characters to pipes.  I should be using single quotes around the echo; then the backslashes wouldn't be necessary.  I just followed the question's code quietly.

Comment: bsd sed seems completely hosed!  `echo a,b,c | sed -E -e 's/,|$/:/g'` is giving me `a:b:` and deleting the `c`!

Comment: @WilliamPursell: I confirm your finding — and am at a loss for an explanation.  The `-E` option is suddenly more trouble than it's worth.  JFTR, I'm using macOS High Sierra 10.13.2 and the `sed` that comes with it (it doesn't have an option to identify the version, AFAICT).

Comment: My sed also provides no version info.  The man page installed with it is dated 2005, running on darwin 15.6.0 on El Capitan 10.11.6.  This is almost certainly a bug.

Comment: What happens if you change the order of the characters in the bsd sed failed replacement, e.g. try `s/$|^|,/|/g`? One of the multiple ways that BSD awk is broken is that the order matters when you mix character classes with individual characters (e.g. see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/356234/133219) so I'm just wondering if BSD sed is similarly broken. I'd expect `sed 's/,/|/g; s/.*/|&|/'` to work with any sed btw.

Comment: @EdMorton: You get different exhibitions of brokenness.  For example, `echo "a,b,c" | sed -E 's/$|^|,/|/g'` yields
`a|b|`
but `echo "a,b,c" | sed -E 's/^|$|,/|/g'` yields
`|a|b|c`.  The `sed 's/,/|/g; s/.*/|&|/'` variant saves writing one substitution; clever.  Not sure whether two substitutions for beginning and end is quicker than one which has to match the whole line; I doubt if the difference is measurable.  (It works with BSD `sed`, but it is the `-E` option that gives trouble, not classic `sed` notations.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks for checking. So the rule is - if on a BSD system install GNU tools stat!

Comment: @EdMorton: More or less -- at least, install GNU `sed` if you want to use extended regular expressions.  As you can tell, I have both BSD and GNU versions on my Macs, and by default use the BSD version, but I mostly don't bother with the `-E` option.  Clearly, if I use `-E`, I shall need to use GNU `sed` as the BSD variant seems buggy in that area (or, at least, the behaviour is not the same as GNU `sed` and is not readily explicable).  I'm not sure whether to report the trouble or where to report it (to Apple, or the various *BSD teams -- if you have any ideas, I'm open to suggestion).

Comment: BSD awk is broken in several ways too and has been for many years. I've seen other people asking if/where to report bugs but I've never heard of a bug being fixed

Answer (score 1):

Following `sed` may help you in same.

```
echo "a,b,c" | sed 's/^/|/;s/,/|/g;s/$/|/'
```

Output will be as follows.

```
|a|b|c|
```